# Python 3 - openpyxl - Iterating through column by name

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

What is the easiest way using openpyxl to iterate through a column not by number but by column header (string value in first row of ws):

Something like this:

```
for cell in ws.columns['revenue']:
    print(cell.value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Column headers don't exist so you'd have to create something to represent them, presumably based on the names in the first row:

```
headers = {}
for idx, cell in enumerate(ws.iter_rows(min_row=1, max_row=1), start=1):
    headers[cell.value] = idx

revenue = ws.columns[headers['revenue']]
```

`ws.columns` will return **all** columns which could be slow on a large worksheet.

You could also add a named range to represent the relevant cells and loop through that.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer from Charlie Clark, bit slightly modified:

```
headers = {}
for row in work_sheet.iter_rows(min_row=1, max_row=1):
    for cell in row:
        headers[cell.value] = cell.column
```

And when you need to get the value, you can use:

```
value = row[headers['column_name']].value
```